# Modify CABasicAnimation whilst its rotating iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, layer, cabasicanimation

I have a a uiimage that rotates using a CABasicAnimation. When i get a compass update i change/ update the images start point by the time offset.

This works fine but when i get an update from the compass and remove the old animation it jumps back to the start before moving to its new start location. This causes a flashing effect. Is there a away to either remove and add the animation at the same time or prevent this from happening in some way?

My code so far is below.

```
[self.waveImage.layer RemoveAllAnimations];

CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.0 * M_PI];
animation.duration = 1.0;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;    // Repeat forever           
animation.speed = 1.0/duration;
animation.timeOffset = startingPhase;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

[self.waveImageView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transform.rotation.z"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

- Get rid of the fromValue. When you don't specify a fromValue, it uses
  the current value of the animation

  Remove the timePhase. You want to animate the new change from the
  beginning. timePhase will cause it to shift your animation.

  Don't use a repeat count. That will cause the animation to go from
  it's start to end, then snap back and repeat.

  add animation.removedOnCompletion = NO.